# Schedule only when called in 1.16 rc1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The first time I'm using `/schedule` but when I try to call a function using `schedule` from my main function it only works if I schedule it with 1 tick essentially just calling the function. I just tested it in 1.15 and I guess it is intended, but then what is the `/schedule` command good for? Sure you can make the function call itself, but I want the function to only be active whilst I call it from the other function to make it more optimized.

Example: `schedule function pack:data/animation 10t` doesn't work, but
`schedule function pack:data/animation 1t` and `schedule function pack:data/animation 10t replace`
works.

Comment: Is your main function running every tick?

Comment: @MegaCrafter10 yes I run the main every tick through the Minecraft tick function

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your issue with higher delays is, they work exactly the same as shorter ones, but I closed this as a duplicate of one that explains the basics of `/schedule` and also lists alternatives for now. If this is not what you meant, please clarify the difference in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`/schedule` is used to delay the execution of a function. If all you want to do is execute a function from another function, I recommend using `/function pack:data/animation` instead.

Also, running `schedule function pack:data/animation 10t` from your main function won't work since it's executed every tick. The reason is that the main is re-scheduling the execution of the animation function every tick.

Comment: I'm of course already calling functions but thank you for clearing up my confusion about the schedule command. Though my other question is still how would I call a function only at certain times and have it then run at a specific tick? Would I have to make the schedule have tags and remove them? That seems pretty inconvenient

Comment: Another option is to use a scoreboard timer. Simply create a scoreboard objective, increase it by 1 each tick, run the command when the timer reaches a specific value, and reset the timer.